# Ranger: yank name does not copy anything to clipboard

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, clipboard, ranger

I am using:

```
ranger version: ranger-master
Python version: 3.11.8 (main, Feb 12 2024, 14:50:05) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8
```

When I invoke `yank name` using `yn`, nothing happens. I use Arch linux + wayland + sway. How can I fix this ?
Thank you for help